# jquery datatable data-order alternative

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Is there any way to specify **data-order** attribute when setting the datatable's data dynamically?
For example this is what I used to have

```
<td class="sorting_1" data-order="1451599200000">1 Jan 2016</td>
```

Now I'm setting data through **columnDefs**

```
{
    render: function (date) {
        var d = new Date(date);
        var parsedDate = d.getUTCDate() + ' ' + monthsAbbr[d.getUTCMonth()] + ', ' + d.getUTCHours() + ":" + d.getUTCMinutes();
        return parsedDate;
    },
    targets: 4
}
```

So, I'm wondering if there's any API witch I can set the td's data-order atribute.

Answer (score 0):

The `render()` function takes a few more arguments that should help you achieve your goal. Here's an example from the [manual page on renderers](https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers):

```
{
    data: 'created',
    render: function ( data, type, row ) {
        var dateSplit = data.split('-');
        return type === "display" || type === "search" ?
            dateSplit[1] +'-'+ dateSplit[2] +'-'+ dateSplit[0] :
            data;
    }
}
```

Applying this to your case, your `render()` function could be something like this:

```
render: function (data, type, row) {
    if (type === "display" || type === "search") {
        var d = new Date(data);
        var parsedDate = d.getUTCDate() + ' ' + monthsAbbr[d.getUTCMonth()] + ', ' + d.getUTCHours() + ":" + d.getUTCMinutes();
        return parsedDate;
    }

    return data;
}
```

See also the [manual page on orthogonal data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data).